# Dynamic Array C++ (Deletion)

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, i am trying to create a dynamic array which has 4 functions (insert, delete, search and print). I have managed to do the insertion part but am not sure how to go on about with the 'deleting' function.

this is what am trying to achieve:

- Input from user
- Searches for that number
- If found delete
- print new list
  void SDI::Array::remove(int removeData)

this is my Array header file

```
#ifndef ARRAY
#define ARRAY

namespace SDI
{
typedef int StoredData;

class Array
{
private:
    int Capacity;
    int size;
    StoredData * bufferPtr;
public:
    Array();
    ~Array();
    void insert (int addData);
    void remove (int removeData);
    int search (int searchData);
    void print();

};
}

#endif



void SDI::Array::remove(int removeData)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(bufferPtr[i] == removeData)
        {
            removeData = bufferPtr[i];
            int newSize = size -1;
            //copy existing data
            //delete removeData
            //print array list without the deleted element
        }
    }
}
```

any advice is appreciated

thanks

Comment: You should specify at least what bufferPtr is. And `bufferPtr[removeData]` looks suspicious at best.

Comment: `removeData` is an array index or a value need to be found and delete?

Comment: ^^ its the value that need to be found and deleted

Comment: Then you should probably post other parts of the code as it is very unclear !

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
void SDI::Array::remove(int removeData)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(bufferPtr[i] == removeData)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<size;j++)
            {
                bufferPtr[j-1]=bufferPtr[j];
            }
            size--;
            int newSize = size-1;
            break;
        }
    }
   printf(bufferPtr);
}
```

Comment: It should be `size--;` not `newSize = size - 1`

Comment: Yeah it is, I tried to write the code so that it remains similar to what he posted ! Thanks for the help !

Comment: You should probably have a check to the other parts of the code and the way you are calling the above function through objects !

Answer (score -1):

You can't resize an array, dynamic or otherwise. If you wish to truly remove an element in an array. you must create an identical array that has been sized properly to replace the old one.